# I am using group by keyword but it grouping 'h' and 'H' into one

Tags: mysql

In my table student,when I use group by keyword as like

```sql
Select * from student group by details;
```

It grouping 'Home' and 'home' into only 'home' .(home come before Home in table)
Why it is happening??..

Comment: I reject the premise of the question. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate

Answer (score 1):

It's due to collation settings.

When you use `whatever_ci`, it'd be grouping together (because `case insensitive`). Use case sensitive collation instead.